# No 3G or 4G on my Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 3g, nexus-4, 4g

I'm not sure why its not working, just having some issues. But, neither 3G nor 4G is working on my device, I believe 2G is though. I'm on T-Mobile and had no issues with installation.

A note; When I try to enter a custom APN, it erases or hides the APNs and I can't see them again until I restart the phone.

I'm running Ubuntu Touch Devel-Proposed on my Nexus 4 by TMobile.

Comment: Ubuntu of course. I'm running Ubuntu Devel-Proposed.

Comment: It is better to explicitly mention it in the question since your tags and the heading also don't suggest the same. Otherwise, the question may be closed as off-topic...

Comment: This is a bug in ofono not supporting ipv6. A work around is documented in the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ofono/+bug/1331813